# Application can not find OpenSSL used to compile library

Tags: java, c, openssl, solaris, solaris-10

I have an application that uses the JNI to call a C file that reads some system information.  I have this running fine on Linux, but on Solaris 10 (SPARC, 32-bit) I am having trouble when the library is used.  I compiled the C file on the same machine that I am testing it on with the command:

```
gcc -O2 -fPIC -shared -static-libgcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include \
    -I$JAVA_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include/solaris -lcrypto \
    -lm -std=c99 -o libosaccess.so osaccess.c
```

This compiles fine, but unlike on Linux, I had to include the path to the system OpenSSL, `-I/usr/local/ssl/include`.  This is obviously the problem, as when the library is used, I get the following fatal error due to an OpenSSL type:

```
ld.so.1: java: fatal: relocation error: file /workspace/solaris_sparc/libosaccess.so: symbol EVP_aes_256_cbc: referenced symbol not found
Killed
```

I have tried adding the location of the system OpenSSL to the `PATH` and also my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but continue to get the error.  I have read that I can see the paths that my application is looking using `ldd -d` but can't quite seem to get this working as of yet.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way I can set where the OpenSSL files are so that all applications can find them?  On my Linux machine, there are no environment variables that include the path to the OpenSSL on that.  There is, however, a binary called `openssl` under `/usr/bin`, which is included in the `PATH` variable.  I have found a binary on Solaris, but adding this to the `PATH` doesn't help.

**EDIT**

@ nudzo and Kenster

Ok so rather than try to squeeze this into the comments box for your answers, I thought I'd post it in addition to my question to improve the readability.

So I have checked my system and there is only the two copies of OpenSSL that I can find.

- Doing a `pkginfo | grep 'SUNWcry*'` shows that I have the two additional packages installed.
- Only the `/usr/sfw` location has the two 'extra' libraries you mentioned
- Both locations have the `evp.h` header file that includes the `EVP_aes_256_cbc` symbol.

The locations are:

**/usr/sfw**

```
xxx-1035> find /usr/sfw -type f -name 'openssl'
 /usr/sfw/bin/openssl
xxx-1036> find /usr/sfw -type f -name 'evp.h'
 /usr/sfw/include/openssl/evp.h
xxx-1037> find /usr/sfw -type f -name 'libcrypto*'
 /usr/sfw/lib/sparcv9/libcrypto.so.0.9.7
 /usr/sfw/lib/sparcv9/libcrypto_extra.so.0.9.7
 /usr/sfw/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7
 /usr/sfw/lib/libcrypto_extra.so.0.9.7
xxx-1038> find /usr/sfw -type f -name 'libssl*'
 /usr/sfw/lib/sparcv9/libssl.so.0.9.7
 /usr/sfw/lib/sparcv9/libssl_extra.so.0.9.7
 /usr/sfw/lib/libssl.so.0.9.7
 /usr/sfw/lib/libssl_extra.so.0.9.7
```

**/usr/local/ssl**

```
xxx-1040> find /usr/local/ssl -type f -name 'openssl'
 /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl
xxx-1041> find /usr/local/ssl -type f -name 'evp.h'
 /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/evp.h
xxx-1042> find /usr/local/ssl -type f -name 'libcrypto*'
 /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a
 /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7
 /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
 /usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
xxx-1043> find /usr/local/ssl -type f -name 'libssl*'
 /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a
 /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.0.9.7
 /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
 /usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
```

I recompiled my C file using:

```
gcc -O2 -fPIC -shared -static-libgcc \
    -I$JAVA_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include/solaris \
    -I/usr/sfw/include -L/usr/sfw/lib -R/usr/sfw/lib \
    -lcrypto -lm -std=c99 -o libosaccess.so osaccess.c
```

Again, omission of the path to the headers throws `implicit declaration of function` errors of the EVP types when compiling.  This, however, still causes the same error as originally posted.

So if there are only these two copies on the system, that would indicate that instead of using the version shipped with Solaris (`/usr/sfw`), the system default is using the `/usr/local` copy that doesn't have the additional 'extra' shared objects.  Would that be a fair assumption to make?  How would I conclusively check this?  I don't have permissions to remove either copy.

Also, running `cryptoadm list -mv` output a lot of information I didn't quite understand.  However I found these entries in a couple of the slot tables:

```
CKM_AES_CBC                  16   32   .  X  X  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  X  X  .  .
```

and also:

```
Kernel software providers:
==========================
aes256: CKM_AES_ECB,CKM_AES_CBC,CKM_AES_CTR

Kernel hardware providers:
==========================
n2cp/0: CKM_DES_CBC,...,CKM_AES_CBC,...
```

I apologise for the huge amount of extra information.

Comment: Using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be the way to go...how are you using it? I've never had to use it in conjunction with Java before, but I suspect it's not getting passed through to where ever it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the linker were failing to find a shared library, it would give you a different error. Your problem is that the linker is finding all of the libraries that it thinks it should, but it's not finding a symbol for `EVP_aes_256_cbc`.

It seems that there is an issue with this symbol on Solaris 10. See some of these links:

- http://fixunix.com/ssh/73273-openssh-solaris-10-amd64.html
- https://forums.proftpd.org/smf/index.php?topic=3782.0
- http://marc.info/?l=libssh2-devel&m=121642790624715
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.solaris/jFDuAe3-OJQ
- http://trac.libssh2.org/ticket/46

The solution seems to be to make sure you have both SUNWcry and SUNWcryr installed, if you're using those packages for crypto. And look for a library named libcrypto_extra.so or libssl_extra.so, and include that when linking.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I have posted my reply as an edit in the original question.

Comment: If you want to use the libs in /usr/local/ssl/lib, try adding `-L` and `-R` options to make sure you're using those both at link time and at run time. Regarding your attempt to link with the libs in /usr/sfw/lib, I notice you didn't link with the *_extra libraries. Try adding those to the link command.

Comment: Ah right, sorry. I presumed that specifying the directory with the `-L` and `-R` options was enough for the linker to find them.  So I need to explicitly specify the file names within both options?  Thanks again for responding.

Comment: Using the `-L` and `-R` commands using the `/usr/local/ssl` copy worked.  Thanks for all you help, including @nudzo.

Answer (score 0):

I think your link time and run time OpenSSL are different. Solaris have OpenSSL in `/usr/sfw` and I recommend you to use rather that one. Especially when you use Solaris bundled `gcc`. Another good reason is, that this OpenSSL has PKCS11 crypto engine, which you can bind to Solaris PKCS11 token and then you can use full power of hardware crypto accelerators. Run `cryptoadm list -mv` to get your hardware capabilities.

To link it properly add `-L/usr/sfw/lib -R/usr/sfw/lib` and as mentioned above also add `libcrypto_extra.so`, `libssl_extra.so` cause those holds strong crypto ciphers... you know, those comic export laws.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I have posted my reply as an edit in the original question.